# Background turns black when playing with border in CSS

Tags: html, css

I was playing with CSS and wrote the following code:

```
<style>
    .triangle {
        border-width: 50px;
        border-style: solid;
        width: 0;
        height: 0;
    }
    #triangle1 {
        border-bottom-color: red;
    }
</style>

<div id="triangle1" class="triangle"></div>
```

As expected, a red triangle shows up, but there's also a black background behind:
[image]

What's wrong with the code?

Comment: just add color:#fff; to .triangle.

Comment: That will change color of text inside the div. This triangle is actually the bottom border of the div

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't set the color for top, left and right border, so it takes the inherited color value (as no value has been set, it takes black by default). To set the other borders color just add this to the triangle styles.

```
border-top-color: transparent;
border-left-color: transparent;
border-right-color: transparent;
```

See demo http://codepen.io/8odoros/pen/EyLQpd

Comment: not black, but inherit `color` value of element, please edit it

Answer (score 2):

You should set the other borders to color `transparent`

```
.triangle {
    ...
    border-color: transparent;
    ...
}
```

See [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dznsdcmt/)

Answer (score 0):

```
#triangle1 {
    border-color: white white red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can target your `border-color` in two ways i.e either directly as below,

```
.triangle {
        border-width: 50px;
        border-style: solid;
        width: 0;
        height: 0;
    }
 #triangle1 {
        border-color:transparent;
        border-bottom-color: red;
    }
```

Leaving the `border-bottom-color` i.e assigned to `border-bottom` it makes remaining `3` side as transparent.

Or you could target them individually, as below i.e for `border-top` , `border-right` , `border-bottom` or `border-left`.

```
.triangle {
        border-width: 50px;
        border-style: solid;
        width: 0;
        height: 0;
    }
#triangle1 {
        border-top-color:transparent;
        border-right-color:transparent;
        border-left-color:transparent;
        border-bottom-color: red;
    }
```